# serializable issue with Context and transient

Tags: java, android, android-context, serializable, transient

I'm facing an issue with Parcelable and Serializable. All my attributes from a class are Serializable unless Context. In the case of Context I've done this object **transient** so I shouldn't have Serializable problems. 
My issue is that I keep having parceable problems only in devices with API < 11. 
Could devices with API < 11 have problems with **transient**?

Comment: Define "parceable problems", possibly with a stacktrace. `transient` and `Serializable` are available from API Level 1 on and should therefore work on any level.

Comment: If you're using Parcelable you don't have to worry about transient, cause you're the one who controls what data goes into the Parcel.

Comment: I was having the same thoughts as @zapl about API Level 1 and actually it's true, the error came from other side and it's already solved. Thanks